# Scrollable CardView not respondig to click

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that contains CardView with a ScrollView. But the CardView does not respond to clicks. When I remove the ScrollView it work perfectly. Is there any way of making it respond to clicks with the ScrollView?

My CardView looks like this;

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <ScrollView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">


  </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Having scrollview inside another scrollable view (recyclerview) will cause such problems.

Comment: @Santosh please Post click code or refer coderzpassion.com for tutorials.You should use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot put a scrollview inside the another scrollview, In this case your recyclerview by default it is scrollable , so when you put another scrollview inside the recycler view the scroll conflict will appear, In wise word it doesnt support that kind of behaviour.

**Note**
You can use recyclerview inside scrollView only when you know the height of the recycler or u need to calculate the height.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried using NestedScrollView and also changed the height of recyclerview to a fixed value. But it is still not clickable.

Comment: I have checked recycler view inside the scroll view will work with fixed height but It is not possible to put scrollview inside the recycler view as far as i no because i have tried now.I have edited the answer.